# startManagedCursor (c) versus c.close()?

Tags: android-sqlite, android-cursor

Wondering how startManagedCursor() acts on / versus db.close() and / or cursor.close() Did read docs, but I'm still fuzzy on it %-) ... and, understood that startManagedCursor() is deprecated api >= 11.  I *think* I have to use it for < android 2.3.x.

Two questions are in the code comments. Thanks !

***SOR !*** ... SO Rocks :)

```
Cursor c = null;
try {           
        dbHelper.open() ;
        c = dbHelper.getMyRecords() ;
        startManagingCursor(c) ;

        if ( c.moveToFirst() ) {  uberCool (stuff, here) ; }

        dbHelper.close() ;// <** Question 1 : Is cursor also closed here ?

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d ("OOPS", Caught exception: " + e.toString() ) ;

    } finally {
        // ** Question 2 : Is the close() just below redundant 
        //               - will the managed cursor just close when function
        //                 goes out of scope  ?
        if (c != null) c.close() ; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that a managed cursor is owned by the activity. I have used one with a `ListView` inside a `ListActivity`. The primary reason for this is that the views in the `ListView` are automatically updated when the data changes in the data source (in my case a SQLite database) underlying the `Cursor`. I believe that the `Cursor` is closed when the `Activity` which manages it is killed. Calling `close()` in the finally block might be redundant. It depends first that my assumption is correct and also when this code is executed.

Comment: Thanks Code-Guru ... gave you the Big Check Mark :)) as my tests confirm your observations.